# Angular 8: How to Show Loader/Spinner only on particular components on different router-outlet based on HTTP Response?

Tags: spinner, angular8, router-outlet

How can I Show Loader/Spinner only on particular components on different router-outlet based on HTTP Response,
For Example, I have different modules and i want spinner to show on that router-outlet only when any HTTP Request is done on that module's components only.

Answer (score 0):

Use ng-block-ui library which is popular for show loader for specific div, specific router module and easy to customize.

```
npm install ng-block-ui --save
```

Include the BlockUIModule in your main app module.

```
import { BlockUIModule } from 'ng-block-ui';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BlockUIModule.forRoot()
  ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Here is the following example for specific showing loading in specific div or container.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'cmp',
  template: `
    <ng-template #blockTemplate>
      <div class="block-ui-template">
        <img src="logo.png" />
      </div>
    </ng-template>

    <block-ui [template]="blockTemplate">
      <!-- Your app markup here -->
    </block-ui>
  `
})
export class Cmp {}
```

Even you should be customize some of loading time delay, loading size as per your router URL or data load events.